Laravel 10 - Inertia.js not working after installing laravel-tenancy package in Laravel Breeze application
I recently installed the Laravel Breeze authentication package in my Laravel application, which includes Inertia.js and React. Subsequently, I integrated the multitenancy feature using the package composer require stancl/tenancy. However, after this integration, I encountered an issue where Inertia.js stopped working when attempting to navigate to the login URL. Below is a screenshot of the error appearing in the browser console.
Inertia.js should function normally and allow navigation to the login URL after integrating laravel-tenancy package.here is what i am getting in console
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8000/login' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-inertia is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.The FetchEvent for "http://localhost:8000/login" resulted in a network error response: an object that was not a Response was passed to respondWith(). chunk-PZLFA75S.js?v=d57ed256:1513  GET http://localhost:8000/login net::ERR_FAILED AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
error screenshot from console
